# How to control for loop?

Tags: bash

Let's say we have "for loop" as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(cat test_file); do 
echo $i
done
```

The content of text file is names of folders in a parent folder

If the text_file contains 10000 entries (i.e. variable i), how can I tell "for loop" to sleep 10 seconds between every 10 "echos".
In other words when for loop reads the variable i in the text_file how can I control the number of variables that for loop can run every specific period of time? So the output as follow:

```
   Variable #1
   Variable #2
   Variable #3
   .
   .
   .
   .
   sleep 10
    Variable #11
    Variable #12
    Variable #13
   .
   .       .
```

Comment: count the iterations and see when dividing by ten results in a whole number; when that condition exist (mod 10) you simply thread sleep for 10 seconds.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: `for i in 1 2 3; do stuff; done` waits for `stuff` to complete on each iteration so not sure how they would "work at the same time"... oh well...

Comment: @ don_crissti. Thank you! This approach is very helpful if you want to apply a bunch of commands on a very large number of images. (i.e. you put the commands between two brackets as follow (command 1; command 2 command 3 ... etc )&. This will apply all the commands on all the images at once. In order to avoid "out of memory" I like how the approach bellow controlled  the resources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following ***bash*** script (*to sleep 10 seconds between every 10 "echos"*):

`test.sh` is a test name of the script

```
#!/bin/bash
while ((++i)); read -r line
do
    echo "$line"
    if (( "$i" % 10 == 0)) 
    then
        sleep 10
    fi
done < $1
```

---

***Usage***:

```
bash test.sh test_file
```

---

`while ((++i))` - will increment `i` counter each time when `read -r line` returns a line from the input

`if (( "$i" % 10 == 0))` - checks if current line number `i` is divisible by `10` (means that the execution flow reaches next 10 lines)

`sleep 10` - pauses the script for 10 seconds

Answer (score -1):

```
xargs -L 10 sh -c 'printf "%s\n" "$@"; sleep 10' sh < test_file
```

### Working

- `xargs` with `-L` will take 10 lines in one go and pass them on to `sh -c` command. There the first argument is consumed as name of program, we will place a dummy name `sh`. Then these 10 lines will be available to `sh` as "$@" and we can do whatever we want. Here we just print them. Then we `sleep` for 10 secs. After that `xargs` shall pass on the next 10 tranche and this cycle repeats till it runs out of lies in test_file.

Comment: @heemayl I am sorry for not giving any workings of the code. Updated.