# How do I process my data file in bunches (without using the app parallel)?

Tags: bash, jobs

I have an analysis program and a text file with data in it which for the sake of exposition I will call `wibble` and `data.txt` respectively.

I tried a simple `for` loop to process all of my data:

```
for i in $(cat data.txt); do
    wibble $i
done
```

But it takes a very long time to finish the analysis one by one.

So I tried making it spin off separate jobs for each datum:

```
for i in $(cat data.txt); do
    ( wibble $i ) &
done
```

But this many analysis processes running causes a memory crash!

So I want to spin up analysis processes in groups of, say, five.  I want to take the first five data items, spin up an analysis process on those; then take the next five and do the same; and so on.

**How can I do that without using the program "parallel' as explained in previous posts (bellow)? I don't have sudo permission on my institutional workstation to install this app, so I am trying to accomplish this goal using simpler code.**

```
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/299346/running-commands-at-once
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/361505/how-to-control-for-loop
```

Comment: Thank you for the question. I am working on analyzing data. I have large number of variables in "readme.txt". For loop will take a very long time to finish the analysis one by one. When I add (echo $i )& this will apply for loop on all the variables in "readme.txt" at once. However, this will cause memory crash! For so, I am thinking of applying for loop on a specific number of variables in readme,.txt (e.g. run every five variables together).

Comment: `for i in $(cat readme.txt)` does *not* iterate over lines. It iterates over words.

Comment: @ jordanm, thank you for correcting me. I fixed it in the body of the question.

Comment: As well as (or perhaps instead of) using `parallel` or `xargs`, why not modify your `wibble` program so that it reads its own input?  A very large part of your performance problem is due to a) using a shell loop to iterate over the contents of a text file, and b) running `wibble` repeatedly, once for each iteration of the loop.   This is about the slowest possible way to do what you want.   BTW, what does `wibble` actually do?  What kind of program is it? compiled binary?  script?

Comment: I have just discovered that the questioner asked almost the same question 10 months ago at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/361505/ .  And `parallel` was mentioned in the questioner's even earlier question about this a year and a half ago at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/299346/ .

Comment: Also you have a reopen vote regarding your own question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With GNU `xargs`:

```
xargs -rn 1 -P 5 -a file wibble
```

That runs up to 5 `wibble` commands in `P`arallel each taking 1 word from the `file` as argument.

For GNU `xargs` words are delimited by sequences of space, tab or newline character and with single quotes, double quotes and backslash recognised as quoting operators for those delimiters and for each other.

For *words* to be each line of the the file, add a `-d '\n'`.

For *words* to be treated like in your approach where on `bash`, they are by default (unless `$IFS` was modified) delimited on space, tab and newline and also subject to filename generation, you'd do something like:

```
xargs -rn 1 -P 5 -0a <(printf '%s\0' $(<file)) wibble
```

That is, have the shell perform that split+glob and `printf` pass the resulting words to `xargs`.

Comment: This is genius!!!!! Thank you so much! I spent a very long time trying to figure out how to do it!

Comment: Actually, this command apply  "wibble " five time on every variable in file